# Why can we use `nil` to get members

Tags: go

I am studying `http`  source codes of `Golang`, I found [this](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/e550c3054586a224d949cc8fa030bac0887bee51/src/net/http/request.go#L873)

```
func NewRequestWithContext(ctx context.Context, method, url string, body io.Reader) (*Request, error) {
    ...
    rc, ok := body.(io.ReadCloser)
    ...
}
```

but this `body` is `nil`, it is passed in the following way

```
func NewRequest(method, url string, body io.Reader) (*Request, error) {
    return NewRequestWithContext(context.Background(), method, url, body)
}
func (c *Client) Get(url string) (resp *Response, err error) {
    req, err := NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return c.Do(req)
}
```

Function `Get` passes `nil` to function `NewRequest`,

function `NewRequest` passes this `nil` to function `NewRequestWithContext`,

then function  `NewRequestWithContext` use `nil` to call `nil.(io.ReadCloser)`, why does not it cause `panic`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement `rc, ok := body.(io.ReadCloser)` is a [type assertion](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Type_assertions) used in the assignment special form. When `body` is nil, `rc` is set to nil and `ok` is set to false.

Answer (score 5):

The statement

```
    rc, ok := body.(io.ReadCloser)
```

tests if `body` is a  `ReadCloser`. If not, then `rc` will be set to `nil`, and `ok` will be set to `false`.

If the code was:

```
rc:=body.(io.ReadCloser)
```

then with a nil body, it would panic.